# pod install fails with dylib not found

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

My podfile   is this.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Task Tracker' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Task Tracker
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10'
end
```

I am trying to run `pod install`
It gives me error `LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): dependent dylib '@rpath/libffi.7.dylib' not found for '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle`

What I tried

```
gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Still same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Intel chip Mac and getting this error after trying the above command also, it's because of the cocoa pods installed on your Mac (Not installed properly). Completely remove the cocoapods and install it again from the beginning. This solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Jump to /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib, and ln -s libffi.8.dylib libffi.7.dylib

tips: libffi.8.dylib is your current ffi lib

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).